# Remove duplicates by columns A, keeping the row with the highest value in column B

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas

I have a dataframe with repeat values in column A.  I want to drop duplicates, keeping the row with the highest value in column B.

So this:

```
A B
1 10
1 20
2 30
2 40
3 10
```

Should turn into this:

```
A B
1 20
2 40
3 10
```

I'm guessing there's probably an easy way to do this—maybe as easy as sorting the DataFrame before dropping duplicates—but I don't know groupby's internal logic well enough to figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the URL in the question appears EOL.

Comment: For an idiomatic and performant way, [see this solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650846/3707607).

Comment: Time has marched on... As of this writing, I believe [this solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876659/758174) is faster (at least in the case where there are lots of duplicates) and also simpler.

Answer (score 380, accepted):

This takes the last. Not the maximum though:

```
In [10]: df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep="last")
Out[10]: 
   A   B
1  1  20
3  2  40
4  3  10
```

You can do also something like:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('A', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.B.idxmax()])
Out[12]: 
   A   B
A       
1  1  20
2  2  40
3  3  10
```

Comment: Small note: The `cols` and `take_last` parameters are depreciated and have been replaced by the `subset` and `keep` parameters. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: as @Jezzamon says, `FutureWarning: the take_last=True keyword is deprecated, use keep='last' instead`

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `df.sort_values(by=['B']).drop_duplicates(subset=['A'], keep='last')`? I mean this sort_values seems safe to me but I have no idea if it actually is.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. See @Ted Petrou's answer below.

Comment: If you want to use this code but with the case of more than one column in the `group_by`, you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` 
`df.groupby(['A','C'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.B.idxmax()]).reset_index(drop=True)`
This will reset the index as its default value would be a Multindex compsed from `'A'` and `'C'`

Comment: Does this solution works for keep “first” instead of “last”? Thanks

Comment: This solution does not seem to work for me. I have a column of dates and am trying to remove duplicate dates keeping highest value in other columns. No error but all dates are still there. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jezrael for the same question how to groupby multiple columns and keep the maximum value

Comment: its workd with me, but if the data like this : `data = {'A'=[ 1 ,1 ,1,2 ,2, 3] 'B':[10 ,20 ,20 ,30 ,40 ,10]}`
is there any way to remove a duplicated and keep the **max** value and the **equal** also, exepected: `output= {'A'=[ 1 ,1 ,2, 3] 'B':[20 ,20 ,40 ,10]}`

Answer (score 161):

The top answer is doing too much work and looks to be very slow for larger data sets. `apply` is slow and should be avoided if possible. `ix` is deprecated and should be avoided as well.

```
df.sort_values('B', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('A').sort_index()

   A   B
1  1  20
3  2  40
4  3  10
```

Or simply group by all the other columns and take the max of the column you need. `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).max()`

Comment: This is actually a cleaver approach. I was wondering if it can be generalized by using some `lamba` function while dropping. For example how can I drop only values lesser than say average of those duplicate values.

Comment: This is slower than `groupby` (because of the initial `sort_values()` which is `O[n log n]` and that `groupby` avoids). See [a 2021 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876659/758174).

Comment: I’d rather sort ascending (default) and keep last record for the sake of self-explainability : `df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A', keep='last').sort_index()`.

Answer (score 58):

**Simplest solution:**

To drop duplicates based on one column:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('column_name', keep='last')
```

To drop duplicates based on multiple columns:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['col_name1','col_name2','col_name3'], keep='last')
```

Comment: Best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. @Flavio

Comment: My data frame has 10 columns, and I used this code to delete duplicates from three columns. However, it deleted the rows from the rest of the columns. Is there any way to delete the duplicates only for the 4 last columns?

Comment: But OP wants to keep the highest value in column B.    This might work if you sorted first.  But then it's basically Ted Petrou's answer.

Comment: remember to assign df back to df `df = df.drop_duplicates`. doing `df.drop_duplicates(...)` alone won't work

Comment: This answer assumes that the columns are sorted, which was not specified in the question.

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks a lot

Comment: This solution is wrong. You need to sort your dataframe ascending first for this solution to work reliably.

Answer (score 34):

I would sort the dataframe first with Column B descending, then drop duplicates for Column A and keep first

```
df = df.sort_values(by='B', ascending=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep="first")
```

without any groupby

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['A']).max()
```

Comment: D'you know the best idiom to reindex this to look like the original DataFrame?  I was trying to figure that out when you ninja'd me. :^)

Comment: Neat.  What if the dataframe contains more columns (e.g. C, D, E)?  Max doesn't seem to work in that case, because we need to specify that B is the only column that needs to be maximized.

Comment: @DSM Check the link in the original question.  There's some code to reindex the grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

I was brought here by a link from a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68876376/758174).

For just two columns, wouldn't it be simpler to do:

```py
df.groupby('A')['B'].max().reset_index()
```

And to retain a full row (when there are more columns, which is what the "duplicate question" that brought me here was asking):

```py
df.loc[df.groupby(...)[column].idxmax()]
```

For example, to retain the full row where `'C'` takes its max, for each group of `['A', 'B']`, we would do:

```py
out = df.loc[df.groupby(['A', 'B')['C'].idxmax()]
```

When there are relatively few groups (i.e., lots of duplicates), this is faster than the `drop_duplicates()` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650846/758174) (less sorting):

Setup:

```py
n = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(0, 20, n),
    'B': np.random.randint(0, 20, n),
    'C': np.random.uniform(size=n),
    'D': np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), size=n),
})
```

(Adding `sort_index()` to ensure equal solution):

```py
%timeit df.loc[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].idxmax()].sort_index()
# 101 ms ± 98.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.sort_values(['C', 'A', 'B'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['A', 'B']).sort_index()
# 667 ms ± 784 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: YMMV.  In a small real use case with 1 % duplicates, the `drop_duplicates()` solution proved 13 times faster than the `groupby()` one.

Comment: And it’s even faster if you don’t sort by 'A' and 'B' : `df.sort_values(by='C', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['A', 'B']).sort_index()`.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this:

```
# First you need to sort this DF as Column A as ascending and column B as descending 
# Then you can drop the duplicate values in A column 
# Optional - you can reset the index and get the nice data frame again
# I'm going to show you all in one step. 

d = {'A': [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1], 'B': [30, 40,50,42,38,30,25,32]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    A   B
0   1   30
1   1   40
2   2   50
3   3   42
4   1   38
5   2   30
6   3   25
7   1   32


df = df.sort_values(['A','B'], ascending =[True,False]).drop_duplicates(['A']).reset_index(drop=True)

df

    A   B
0   1   40
1   2   50
2   3   42
```

Answer (score 4):

I think in your case you don't really need a groupby. I would sort by descending order your B column, then drop duplicates at column A and if you want you can also have a new nice and
clean index like that:

```
df.sort_values('B', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('A').sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: how is this any different than other posts?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last')
```

I referred this from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation I had to solve that's worth sharing: for each unique string in `columnA` I wanted to find the most common associated string in `columnB`.

`df.groupby('columnA').agg({'columnB': lambda x: x.mode().any()}).reset_index()`

The `.any()` picks one if there's a tie for the mode. (Note that using `.any()` on a Series of `int`s returns a boolean rather than picking one of them.)

For the original question, the corresponding approach simplifies to

`df.groupby('columnA').columnB.agg('max').reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

When already given posts answer the question, I made a small change by adding the column name on which the max() function is applied for better code readability.

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].max()
```

Comment: Please give a little more context to your answers, explaining how they work and why they are superior or complementary to the answers already available for a question. If they do not provide added value, please refrain from posting additional answers on old questions. Finally, please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code as a code block by indenting it.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar method to the selected answer, but sorting data frame by multiple columns might be an easier way to code.

Firstly, sort the date frame by both `"A"` and `"B"` columns, the `ascending=False` ensure it is ranked from highest value to lowest:

```
df.sort_values(["A", "B"], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Then, drop duplication and keep only the first item, which is already the one with the highest value:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you end up here, and have a dataframe with several equal columns (and some of them are different) and want to keep the original index:

```
df = (df.sort_values('B', ascending=False)
         .drop_duplicates(list(final_out_combined.columns.difference(['B'],sort=False)))
         .sort_index())
```

in the line `drop_duplicates` you can add the columns which can have a difference, so for example:

```
drop_duplicates(list(final_out_combined.columns.difference(['B', 'C'],sort=False)))
```

would mean `B` and `C` are not checking for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

this also works:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'A':a.groupby('A')['B'].max().index,'B':a.groupby('A')       ['B'].max().values})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -11):

I am not going to give you the whole answer (I don't think you're looking for the parsing and writing to file part anyway), but a pivotal hint should suffice: use python's `set()` function, and then `sorted()` or `.sort()` coupled with `.reverse()`:

```
>>> a=sorted(set([10,60,30,10,50,20,60,50,60,10,30]))
>>> a
[10, 20, 30, 50, 60]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[60, 50, 30, 20, 10]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong on this, but recasting a pandas DataFrame as a set, then converting it back seems like a very inefficient way to solve this problem.  I'm doing log analysis, so I'll be applying this to some very big data sets.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about this particular scenario, so it may be that my generic answer will not turn out to be too efficient for your problem.