# For the same value in column a, sort values in column b and choose top 5

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has two columns `col_1` and `col_2`. Values in column `col_2` corresponds to values in column `col_1`.

```
print (df)
   col_1  col_2
1      a     12
2      a     33
3      a     11
4      a      4
5      a     42
6      a     66
7      a      9
8      b     12
9      b     34
10     b     42
11     b     64
12     b     86
13     b      2
```

What i am trying to do is that for each value in `col_1` `(a, b, c,..)`, i want to sort the corresponding values in `col_2` and select ONLY the top 5 values. The new dataframe is expected to be like this:

[image]

I tried the of dropping duplicates applied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest) since `col_2` can sometimes have duplicates. But, it didn't work.

```
df.sort_values('col_2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('col_a').sort_index()
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead `drop_duplicates` function [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) and also add first column to [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with ascending sorting:

```
n = 5
df1 = df.sort_values(['col_1','col_2'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('col_1').head(n)
print (df1)
   col_1  col_2
6      a     66
5      a     42
2      a     33
1      a     12
3      a     11
12     b     86
11     b     64
10     b     42
9      b     34
8      b     12
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to assign a variable, can be `df.sort_values('col_2', ascending=False).groupby('col_1').head(5)`, however it doesn't provide the exact expected data.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`GroupBy.Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)

```
df.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].nlargest(5)
```

**Output**

```
col_1    
a      5     66
       4     42
       1     33
       0     12
       2     11
b      11    86
       10    64
       9     42
       8     34
       7     12
```

To get the correct index, use `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].nlargest(5).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
  col_1  col_2
0     a     66
1     a     42
2     a     33
3     a     12
4     a     11
5     b     86
6     b     64
7     b     42
8     b     34
9     b     12
```

Comment: This results the expected data as OP desired.