# python how to remove duplicate from column A while keeping the max value from B

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to remove duplicate from column A (time scale) while keeping the max value from B(power).
I tried following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = np.loadtxt('test.txt',delimiter=' ')
time = data_file [:,0]
power = data_file[:,1]

max = np.max(power,axis=0)
```

thank you for your support!

Comment: Try using pandas and see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059751/10358176.

Comment: please provide us with a sample input and desired output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data_file).groupby(0).max(1).reset_index().to_numpy()
```

example input output:

datafile:

```
[[5 8]
 [1 2]
 [3 9]
 [5 1]
 [1 9]
 [9 0]
 [5 8]
 [0 7]
 [0 4]
 [8 6]]
```

output:

```
[[0 7]
 [1 9]
 [3 9]
 [5 8]
 [8 6]
 [9 0]]
```