# Selecting the higher of two data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Python Pandas trying to sort some student testing data. On occasion, students will test twice during the same testing window, and I want to save only the highest of the two tests. Here's an example of my dataset.

**Name**    **Score** 
Alice       32 
Alice       75 
John        89 
Mark        40 
Mark        70 
Amy         60

Any ideas of how can I save only the higher score for each student?

Comment: Can't you just `sort_values` on both columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in the dataframe `df`, you can sort by the score in descencing order and drop duplicate names, keeping the first:

```
df.sort_values(by='Score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `groupby`. It works like this:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Score': 'max'})
```

It results in:

```
       Score
Name        
Alice     75
Amy       60
John      89
Mark      70
```

Btw. in that special setup, you could also use `drop_duplicates` to make the name unique after sorting on the score. This would yield the same result, but would not be extensible (e.g. if you later would like to add the average score etc). It would look like this:

```
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Score']).drop_duplicates(['Name'], keep='last')
```

From the test data you posted:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sio= StringIO("""Name Score
Alice 32
Alice 75
John 89
Mark 40
Mark 70
Amy 60 """)

df= pd.read_csv(sio, sep='\s+')
```

Comment: I appreciate your edit, but it is, except for the sorting order, exactly what my answer proposes. :)

Comment: Maybe this is because it is straightforward. We probably won't be nominated for a nobel prize, will we? Btw. Haven't seen your post. Where is it?

Comment: Take it easy. This was not meant to be an offense. :) And considering your last question: I have no idea how fast you can type. :)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest) on StackOverflow.

You can merge two pandas data frames and after that calculate the maximum number in each row. df1 and df2 are the pandas of students score:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Alice': 3,
                    'John': 8,
                    'Mark': 7.5,
                    'Amy': 0},
                    index=[0])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Alice': 7,
                    'Mark': 7},
                    index=[0])

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True)
result = result.T
result["maxvalue"] = result.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: what are `df`, `df1` and `df2` and how is this supposed to work?

Comment: df1 and df2 are two pandas dataframes

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, two of them are:

```python
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Score" : [32, 75, 89, 40, 70, 60],
   ...:             "Name" : ["Alice", "Alice", "John", "Mark", "Mark", "Amy"]})
   ...: df
Out[8]: 
   Score   Name
0     32  Alice
1     75  Alice
2     89   John
3     40   Mark
4     70   Mark
5     60    Amy

In [13]: %time df.groupby("Name").max()
CPU times: user 2.26 ms, sys: 286 µs, total: 2.54 ms
Wall time: 2.11 ms
Out[13]: 
       Score
Name        
Alice     75
Amy       60
John      89
Mark      70

In [14]: %time df.sort_values("Name").drop_duplicates(subset="Name", keep="last")
CPU times: user 2.25 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.25 ms
Wall time: 1.89 ms
Out[14]: 
   Score   Name
1     75  Alice
5     60    Amy
2     89   John
4     70   Mark
```