# Drop duplicates based on subset of columns keeping the rows with highest value in col E & if values equal in E the rows with highest value in col B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Say I have below dataframe:

```
A B C D E
3 2 1 4 5
3 2 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 9 8
9 3 8 5 4
```

I would like to drop duplicates based on columns A, B and C, keeping the rows for which column E is the highest. And if the values in column E are the same, then keeping the rows for which the column D is the highest.

So above dataframe would become:

```
A B C D E
3 2 1 4 5
4 5 6 9 8
9 3 8 5 4
```

I saw a beginning of answer there: [python pandas: Remove duplicates by columns A, keeping the row with the highest value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest/41650846#41650846) but unfortunately I can't find out how to handle the if the values are the same in column E then keep the highest from column D :/

(I am running this code on a quite large dataset)

Any help appreciated !

Comment: If it is fast enough, you can sort the frame first: `df.sort_values(["E", "D"], ascending=[False, False]).drop_duplicates(subset=list("ABC"))`. But there might be a better solution as usual.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (and pretty fast)

Comment: oh nice! do you mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: no prob, go for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort the frame first according to the `E, D` criterion in descending order and then drop the duplicates:

```
df.sort_values(["E", "D"], ascending=[False, False]).drop_duplicates(subset=list("ABC"))
```