# Filter data using max. categorical value of a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Good day, I have this data set of *customers* with their *region* and Date of Birth (*dob*).
Some customers have more than a region assigned, so I need to filter them out and keep only last region on pandas (using max value of string would be good).
I tried to filter using *group-by* but I only manage to display *customer* and *region*, and I need to display the whole row (including *dob*)

Thanks in advance.

**Data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
data = [['A', 'FL', '2000-06-01'], ['B', 'FL', '1999-05-01'], ['C', 'FL', '2000-02-03'], ['C', 'NY', '2000-02-03'], ['D', 'FL', '1990-03-01'], ['E', 'NY', '1999-12-07'], ['E', 'TX', '1999-12-07'], ['F', 'FL', '1995-06-07'], ['F', 'TX', '1995-06-07'],]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['customer', 'region', 'dob'])
```

```
    customer    region  dob
0   A   FL  2000-06-01
1   B   FL  1999-05-01
2   C   FL  2000-02-03
3   C   NY  2000-02-03
4   D   FL  1990-03-01
5   E   NY  1999-12-07
6   E   TX  1999-12-07
7   F   FL  1995-06-07
8   F   TX  1995-06-07
```

**My take:**

```
df.groupby(['customer'], sort=False)['region'].max()
```

*Partial Output*

```
customer
A    FL
B    FL
C    NY
D    FL
E    TX
F    TX
```

**Desired output:**

```
    customer    region  dob
0   A   FL  2000-06-01
1   B   FL  1999-05-01
2   C   NY  2000-02-03
3   D   FL  1990-03-01
4   E   TX  1999-12-07
5   F   TX  1995-06-07
```

Comment: Potential duplicate in [python pandas: Remove duplicates by columns A, keeping the row with the highest value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12497402/15497888)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find another similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values other than region are the same for each customer, you can use `df.groupby('customer').max()`; it's the `['region']` part that's restricting the columns to just region. (Also, you can use just use `customer`, rather than a list containing `customer`). Also, `max` returns the alphabetically last element. If you want the value from the last row, you'll need something different.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the `tail` -> it returns the last row(s) for each grouping, in this case you need just the last (1) row per grouping:

```
df.groupby('customer').tail(1)
Out[279]: 
  customer region         dob
0        A     FL  2000-06-01
1        B     FL  1999-05-01
3        C     NY  2000-02-03
4        D     FL  1990-03-01
6        E     TX  1999-12-07
8        F     TX  1995-06-07
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a drop duplicates instead of grouping.
Use this code

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['customer'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
```

The reset index is just to re-number the index after duplicates are removed.
The output will be as follows:

```
In [12]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['customer'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[12]: 
  customer region         dob
0        A     FL  2000-06-01
1        B     FL  1999-05-01
2        C     NY  2000-02-03
3        D     FL  1990-03-01
4        E     TX  1999-12-07
5        F     TX  1995-06-07
```

Comment: Pro tip, as of `pandas 1.0.0` drop_duplicates has an `ignore_index` keyword argument which allows the index to be ignored without chaining a `reset_index` call. `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['customer'], keep='last', ignore_index=True)` Source: [What’s new in 1.0.0 (January 29, 2020)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#other-enhancements)

Comment: If you wish to sort the data using a variable other than the default and then obtain the row with the maximum value relative to another variable, the following code can be utilized. `df.sort_values(['region'],ascending=True).drop_duplicates(subset= 
  ['customer'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)`