# python pandas: duplicated rows using sort_values and drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, drop-duplicates

I have this dataframe
[image]

in column `stage` I have 4 values :

[image]

I Have duplicates rows in this dataframe, and I wanted to drop them, for example:

[image]

I want to keep row #8015

and I don't have 2 rows with the same `stage` and the same `tweet_id`, for example:

[image]

I tried this solution:

```
twitter_archive = twitter_rchive.sort_values(by='stage', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='tweet_id', keep='first').sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

which I find it in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest/13059751#13059751), But then I've lost 10 `doggo` although I sorted my values and keeped the First occurance.

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data and sample code so that it's easier for people to help instead of images.

Comment: @Aditya How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'tweet_id':89324938479283648628, 'name':'Phineas', 'stage': np.nan}, 
                   {'tweet_id':8932493847987465848628, 'name':'Tilly', 'stage': np.nan}, 
                  {'tweet_id':8932493847987465848628, 'name':'Tilly', 'stage': 'Doggo'}])
df = df.groupby(['tweet_id','name']).agg(tuple).applymap(list).reset_index()
df['stage'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda x : [i for i in x if str(i) != 'nan'])
df['stage'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda x : np.nan if len(x) == 0 else x[0])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

First, theres a typo in your line:

```
twitter_archive = twitter_rchive.sort_values(  #<-- you missing a in archive.sort
...
```

Second, if you wanna keep the stage with value, use .isnull() to drop stage = NaN:

```
twitter_arc2 = twitter_archive.loc[twitter_archive['stage'].isnull()]
```

Hope this help