# Pandas dataframe on python

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like this may be a really easy question but I can't figure it out I have a data frame that looks like this

```
one two three

1   2  3

2   3  3

3   4  4
```

The third column has duplicates if I want to keep the first row but drop the second row because there is a duplicate on row two how would I do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: Remove duplicates by columns A, keeping the row with the highest value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas DataFrame objects have a method for this; assuming `df` is your dataframe, `df.drop_duplicates(subset='name_of_third_column')` returns the dataframe with any rows containing duplicate values in the third column removed.