# Find and Remove Duplicates based on Binary Column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with transaction data as below:

```
data = [['1',5, 'cvs', '4567', '4/6/2020  12:56:40',0,0], 
['1',5, 'cvs', '4567', '4/6/2020  12:56:41',1,0], 
['2',6, 'walgreens', '7897', '4/9/2020  12:56:41',0,0],
['2',7, 'target', '7897', '4/10/2020  12:56:41',0,0],
['2',8, 'walmart', '9898', '4/8/2020  12:56:41',0,1],
['2',6, 'walgreens', '7897', '4/9/2020  12:56:41',1,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'AMOUNT','STORE','CARDNUMBER','PURCHASETIME','DULICATED_FLAG','REVERSAL_FLAG'])
```

I want to find the duplicates here and remove the duplicates. Ideally, I would like to have a table shown as below:

```
ID AMOUNT STORE     CARDNUMBER PURCHASETIME         DUPLICATED_FLAG REVERSAL_FLAG
1    5     cvs         4567      4/6/2020  12:56:40     0             0   
1    5     cvs         4567      4/6/2020  12:56:41     1             0  
2    6     walgreens   7897      4/9/2020  12:56:41     0             0
2    6     walgreens   7897      4/9/2020  12:57:41     1             0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: Remove duplicates by columns A, keeping the row with the highest value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/python-pandas-remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest)

Comment: What are the criteria for a row to count as a duplicate? I fail to see the pattern between the input data and the desired output.

Comment: It looks like `df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'DUPLICATED_FLAG'])` @RJAdriaansen (if you correct the word "DULICATED_FLAG" to "DUPLICATED_FLAG") or potentially `df.sort_values('DUPLICATED_FLAG', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'DUPLICATED_FLAG']).sort_index()`

Comment: For a row to count as duplicate, it requires every column except for `PurchaseTime` and `DUPLICATED_FLAG` to be exact the same but `DUPLICATED_FLAG` need to be opposite. @RJAdriaansen

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates can be found with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html). Since you wish to keep the duplicate rows we need to set `keep=True`. As `duplicated` returns boolean values we can use it to filter the dataframe:

```
data = [['1',5, 'cvs', '4567', '4/6/2020  12:56:40',0,0], 
['1',5, 'cvs', '4567', '4/6/2020  12:56:41',1,0], 
['2',6, 'walgreens', '7897', '4/9/2020  12:56:41',0,0],
['2',7, 'target', '7897', '4/10/2020  12:56:41',0,0],
['2',8, 'walmart', '9898', '4/8/2020  12:56:41',0,1],
['2',6, 'walgreens', '7897', '4/9/2020  12:56:41',1,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'AMOUNT','STORE','CARDNUMBER','PURCHASETIME','DUPLICATED_FLAG','REVERSAL_FLAG'])
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['ID','AMOUNT','STORE','CARDNUMBER','REVERSAL_FLAG'], keep=False)]
```

Result:

|  | ID | AMOUNT | STORE | CARDNUMBER | PURCHASETIME | DUPLICATED_FLAG | REVERSAL_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | cvs | 4567 | 4/6/2020 12:56:40 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | cvs | 4567 | 4/6/2020 12:56:41 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | walgreens | 7897 | 4/9/2020 12:56:41 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 6 | walgreens | 7897 | 4/9/2020 12:56:41 | 1 | 0 |